# connect two interfaces and docker containers

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, docker

There are two containers witch are on same network
compose example:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    A:
        image: alpine:3.18
        container_name: container-a
    B:
        image: custom-alpine-with-two-interfaces
        container_name: container-b
```

in container `B` there are two interfaces: `eth0`(docker default `172.26.0.2/16`) and `eth1`

Also in container `A` I set the default gateway as: `ip route add default via 172.26.0.2` witch is `B`.
Now I want to config container `B` to pass all incoming packages from `eth0` on IP of `A` to `eth1`.

How to achieve that goal?

```
                             (10.10.0.5)              (10.10.0.6)
 container A     <------->   container B   <------->   internet
(172.26.0.3)                 (172.26.0.2)
```

- On `A` when i set `default via 172.26.0.2` and run `traceroute example.com` , it stuck on `172.26.0.1`

```
traceroute to example.com (1.1.1.1), 30 hops max, 46 byte packets
 1  container_b (172.26.0.2)  0.004 ms  0.004 ms  0.004 ms
 2  myshost.local (172.26.0.1)  0.004 ms  0.007 ms  0.006 ms
 3  *  *  *
 4  *  *  *
```

- Also i tried this iptables configs on `B` but nothing happened:

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why you want to do this in iptables. In particular because I suspect that a more fully developed solution will grow more "forwarding rules". For instance :

- Would it grow to have a broader range of second tier containers to which packets should be forwarded.
- Would criteria based on source, destination or packet contents be needed to decide how to do the forwarding.

That is I'm suspecting a more fully featured (reverse) proxy will emerge...

Can you share a bit more of your reasoning?

Comment: `Would it grow to have a broader range of second tier containers to which packets should be forwarded.`: In this particular case, No, there's only one replicate.
`Would criteria based on source, destination or packet contents be needed to decide how to do the forwarding.`: No. all package need to be forwarded.
let me exactly what am I doing. these containers are VPNs, witch `B` has TUN mode and create an interface. so I want to chain this containers and connect to `A`